# Why is heparin contraindicated in patients with severe uncontrolled hypertension?

Tags: hematology, medicine, blood-circulation, blood-pressure

Heparin is a parenteral anti coagulant- prevents clot formation by inhibiting factors 2 a and 10 a mainly. Now, patients with severe uncontrolled hypertension- have persistent bp of more than 140/90. Here we are considering the force exerted by the blood on the wall of the arteries. Increased pressure of blood means, blood is trying to flow through a smaller diameter of the vessel, hence you can say that blood flow is decreased in such patients. Shouldn't heparin be useful in patients of hypertension because it will prevent clots from blocking the blood flow ? Why is it contraindicated ?

Comment: I would suggest that your question is more appropriate for SE Medical Sciences, where you are more likely to receive an authoritative answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.